# Making jsplumb endpoints readonly

Tags: javascript, html, jsplumb

Here is my requirement.
There will be btns which can be connected using jsplumb. When the last connection is given to the END button, then there should not be any option for the user to edit/ change/ remove his connection established. How to do this?
I tried this: `$('#target_div_id,.jsplumb-connector,.jsplumb-endpoint,.jsplumb-overlay').addClass('readonly_div');`

```
.readonly_div{
opacity:0.5;
pointer-events: none ;
background-size:cover;
-webkit-filter: blur(1px);
-moz-filter: blur(1px);
-ms-filter: blur(1px);
-o-filter: blur(1px);
filter: blur(1px);
```

}

But this is not sufficient to make the jsplumb elements readonly.
Any help please!

Answer (score 1):

Use the **ConnectionsDetachable** global property to false to prevent detaching any connection.

```
jsPlumb.importDefaults({
  ...
  ConnectionsDetachable: false
  ...
});
```

Or use **detachable** property to prevent detaching on a specific connection

```
var c = jsPlumb.connect({
    source:"someDiv",
    target:"someOtherDiv",
    detachable: false
});
```

Answer (score 0):

So there's 2 ways to accomplish that:

Either on initializing the endpoint, like this:

```
this.plumbInstance.addEndpoint(endpointName, {
    isEnabled: false,
    /* other plumb endpoint options */
});
```

or, you can also change the endpoints' state:

```
plumbEndpoint.setEnabled(false);
```

By changing `isEnabled` to `false`, you can not drag anything to that connection. However, as far as I've experienced, you can still drop a connection on that endpoint. In order to prevent that I wrote a small method `isValidConnection(endpoint1, endpoint2)` which checks if the endpoints can be connected or not. In that method you can check check if the endpoints are enabled, like this:

```
isValidConnection(endpoint1: Endpoint, endpoint2: Endpoint): boolean {
    const isValid: boolean = endpoint1.isEnabled() && endpoint2.isEnabled();

    // add more checks here if necessary.

    return isValid;
}
```